# Looping over list of items, showing only those that match criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I'm in the need of your help to solve the basic exercise I encountered during the course of learning Excel VBA. So, here it is:

There is a list of rollercoasters, where one column represents the name of the rollercoaster, whilst another column its type. I have to loop down the list, until the empty cell, selecting only those rollercoasters, the type of which is "Wooden". The sub should end with a message box displaying all rollercoasters' names, that matched our "Wooden" criterion (every line of msgbox contains one name).

So, anyone could advise a new learner how to cope with the above...?

Comment: Welcome. You should know that you've show us what have you tried so far, what is working and what is not. So that people here can help you with the issues.

Comment: To clarify @Nelly27281's comment, "code this for me questions" are generally frowned upon around here. Please post anything that you have tried and we would be happy to help you learn how to round your square wheel.

Comment: Hi gentleman, sorry for that, and thanks for the comments

Answer (score 1):

This will run on the first 1000 rows where column a is the rollercoasters and column b is the type. you can cahnge the number 1000 to another number or xldown if you desire.

```
Sub Macro1()

'
Dim Rollers As String
For i = 1 To 1000
If Cells(i, 2) = "Wooden" Then Rollers = Rollers & vbNewLine & Cells(i, 1).Value
If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then MsgBox (Rollers): End
Next i
'
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add to Balinti's answer.  This will get you the last row to use instead of hardcoding 1000

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Then you would have a loop that looked like this

```
For i = 1 To LastRow 

Next i

MsgBox Rollers
```

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the help, however the msgbox doesn't appear at the end of algorithm...

Comment: After your loop add MsgBox Rollers

Comment: If you are using my method of getting the last row to loop to, you can exclude If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then MsgBox (Rollers): End from within your loop.